# How do I get an Epson al-c 1700 printer working?

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I have a brand new epson aculaser c1700 and i'd like to have it working fine on ubuntu 12.04. so i did my homework, kind of, no printer driver comes for this printer in cups ... so i asked epson support who drove me to avasys who no longer handle support since december 2011.

This the question that is still in my mind : as this printer comes with an osx driver which uses cups as printer server, how come no driver can be found for cups?

I tried to get ppd and filters from osx driver and use them to install the printer on ubuntu but no answer from printer and none printed sheet i have .... i'm so disappointed i could cry ...

I'd like to work with someone to get this working fine, please help me!

Answer (score 2):

If Lorezo's solution did not work, these are [Linux drivers for Epson printers](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult) in the AcuLaser line. I was not able to find a C1700 anywhere though. I have used drivers from here for my Epson printer and they work well.

Answer (score -2):

I got it working by downloading and installing the Xerox Phaser 6000/6100 driver from the Xerox support site [here](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/phaser-6000/file-download/itit.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en_GB&contentId=116065&from=downloads&viewArchived=false).

It is a zipped .deb file. It is i386 architecture.